# Terraform taint resource naming convention (v0.11.13)

Tags: kubernetes, redis, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

My module `abc` contains an instance of `redis-ha` deployed to Kubernetes via helm compliments of https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis-ha. I want to `taint` this resource. When I `terraform state list` I see the resource listed as:

- module.abc.module.redis.helm_release.redis-ha[3]

My understanding from https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/11570 is that the `taint` command pre-dates the resource naming convention shown in `state list`. As of v0.12 it will honour the same naming convention.

I'm unfortunately not in a position to upgrade to v0.12.

How do I go about `taint`-ing the resource `module.abc.module.redis.helm_release.redis-ha[3]` pre-v0.12?

I'm happy to taint the entire `redis-ha` deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Terraform v0.11 and earlier, the `taint` command can work with that resource instance like this:

```
terraform taint -module=abc.redis helm_release.redis-ha.3
```

From Terraform v0.12.0 onwards, that uses the standard resource address syntax:

```
terraform taint module.abc.module.redis.helm_release.redis-ha[3]
```

Comment: Command `terraform state list` provides an additional hint by printing all the resource names.